# Density of a football at $0.9c$

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

A rectangular block moving at $0.9c$ will have a length of $0.435l_0$ and mass of $2.298m_0$for a stationary observer. The observer will record a density of $5.28\rho_0$ where $\rho_0$  is the density of the body for the stationary observer when the body was at rest.

Would the density have changed if the body was a sphere of same volume?

According to $SR$, the length of the body along the direction of its velocity contracts. So, the body should be sort of a 3D ellipsoid.

Comment: Insert $m = \rho dV$ into $m =\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$. We know $m_0$ and $v$, we have observed/measured $dV$ (the ellipsoid volume, _not_ the spherical one) and we know it, so $\rho dV =\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $. This is for an average density; if we want to localize $\rho(x,y,z) $ inside the ellipsoid we need to do some further math involving density on a surface along the velocity vector.

Comment: Hi Deechit Poudel. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume definition:
$$V=\int dV=\iiint dxdydz$$
Assume the ball moves along the $x$ direction, so
$$V_1=\iiint \frac{dx}{\gamma}dydz=\frac{V_0}{\gamma}$$
Mass is
$$m_1=\gamma m_0$$
So, the density is
$$\rho_1=\frac{m_1}{V_1}=\gamma^2\rho_0$$
If the speed is $\beta=0.9$, then $\rho_1=5.26\rho_0$. Clearly, density is independent of the shape of the ball.